# Getting Invalid column name 'CompanyLocationId' in entity framework .net core

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

From database I removed column company_location_id from table named Company.
Then I removed property CompanyLocationId from model class.
But I am getting above error.

```
 public DbSet<Company> Company { get; set; }
```

Above property I set in DBContext class.

```
  //[Column("company_location_id")]
    //[ForeignKey(nameof(CompanyLocation))]
    //public int? CompanyLocationId { get; set; }

    [Column("created_by")]
    [ForeignKey(nameof(AppUser))]
    public int CreatedBy { get; set; }

    [Column("creation_date")]
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
```

I commented above property because it I removed that column from table.

But while getting from data from company table then I am getting above error. FYI I am using repository design pattern and entity framework.

Comment: Look at the stack trace to see where the error is coming from, and if you still need help add the broken code to your question. We can't help you without seeing any code or anything.

Comment: What caused the error you encountered? Can you attach the code?

Comment: @Conman_123 I added some sort of code so you can get idea.

Comment: Entity Framework maintains a separate model (alongside your class models) of your database and uses that to generate queries. If you remove a column without updating the model, you're going to get this kind of error. With Code First you should comment/remove the property first, update the model by creating a migration and then (the last thing) run that migration against the database to remove the column. Updating the database manually is not code first and likely to break things.

Comment: @phuzi has answered your question very precisely. After making any changes to your model you should add migration and update your database to avoid any such errors.

Answer (score 1):

VR, You just commented on your property from the DBContext class, but when you open your ADO.NET Entity Data Model (.edmx) file, you will see still that particular column is there in that particular table.

You can do:

1. Update your (.edmx) file by refreshing the table from your database.
2. Remove all entities from your Entity Data Model (.edmx) file and add    it again from your database.

For more information regarding the (.edmx) file, you can read my article [How to create an ADO.NET Entity Data Model (EDM)](https://www.codingvila.com/2019/12/how-to-create-ado-net-entity-data-model-edm-in-asp-net-mvc.html)

I hope this will work for you.